# On Google Cloud, Domain/IP doeson't load but domain/IP with port:8080 does

Tags: ubuntu, networking, google-cloud-platform, ip, devops

I have a Django app ruining on a Docker container on Google Cloud Platform.

It's accessible with :port like `domain/IP:8080` BUT not on `domain/IP`

What might be the problem?

- *nmap & netstat output are listed bellow the image.*

### Here are the Firewall rules:

[image: GCP Firewall rules]

### nmap

```
Host is up (0.0013s latency).
Not shown: 995 filtered ports
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp   open   ssh
80/tcp   closed http
443/tcp  closed https
3389/tcp closed ms-wbt-server
8080/tcp open   http-proxy
```

### netstat -lnp | grep 80

```
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
udp6       0      0 fe80::70cf:23ff:fe8:123 :::*                                -
udp6       0      0 fe80::8830:1bff:fe4:123 :::*                                -
udp6       0      0 fe80::42:13ff:fe38::123 :::*                                -
udp6       0      0 fe80::4001:aff:fe96:123 :::*                                -
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     22590    -                   @/containerd-shim/moby/60315b1bbaa927bf4f0cc5cffd6d4203e40c/shim.sock@
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     18084    -                   /run/containerd/containerd.sock
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your VM isn't actually listening on port 80 or 443, based on your `nmap` output:

```
80/tcp   closed http
443/tcp  closed https
```

Web browsers default to http port 80 (or 443 for https), thats why the port is omitted from those IPs in the URL bars.

You will need to configure your server to listen on port 80.  It does appear that because your firewall is passing traffic on port 8080 that the http-server tag is on the instance, so port 80 is allowed through your firewall.

Since it is in a docker container, presumably you can configure port forwarding to forward to the host's port 80 instead of port 8080, such as via `-p 80:8080` when you start the container.